# How to override CSS of Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-design-system

I want to change the styling of several Lightning Component elements such as:
Changing the background of navigation of Tabset from light grey to blue:

From this[image: Standard Tabset]

To this
[image: The Tabset I want to do (I did that using inspect element)]

The code I written in .cmp file:

```
<aura:component>
<div class="slds-size_1-of-4 slds-p-bottom_xx-large">
    <lightning:tabset variant="scoped" class="test">
        <lightning:tab label="Item One">
            <aura:set attribute="body">
                Hello World

            </aura:set>
        </lightning:tab>

        <lightning:tab label="Item two">
            <aura:set attribute="body">
                Bye World

            </aura:set>
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</div>
```

The code in .css file:

```
.THIS.test {
background-color: blue !important;
```

}

But it won't change, can anyone advise me please ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to target the `<ul>` element that holds the tabs:

```
.THIS .test .slds-tabs_scoped__nav {
background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do that using id ? and how ?

Comment: You can include an id but you still have to target the `.slds-tabs_scoped__nav` class. If you add an id of `test` to your outer div you could then do this: `.THIS#test .slds-tabs_scoped__nav {background-color: blue;}`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the active element as

```
.THIS ul > li.slds-tabs_scoped__item.slds-is-active > a {
   background-color: blue ;
}
```

Result:

[image]

You can use chrome inspect to see which selectors to use. Its easy and works magic. I use it every time

[image]

Comment: Boo `!important` flag.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do that using id ? and how ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between `.THIS` and `.test`.  Without the space, you're selecting only the top element `.THIS` which must ALSO have class `test`.  With the space you'll select child elements of `.THIS`.  It's a subtle but critical difference.

```
.THIS.test  // element that matches BOTH '.THIS' AND '.test'  
.THIS .test // children of .THIS that match '.test'
```

I'm not 100% certain whether `.THIS` refers to your first `div.slds-size_1-of-4` or some wrapper element around your component, but either way it doesn't find `class='test'` on that element, so there are no matches.  And that's why it's not matching the child `tabset` element you're intending without the space in the CSS selector.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do that using id ? and how ?

Comment: It works the same way with ID.  If test was an id instead of a class then: `.THIS #test`

Answer (score 0):

These solutions did not appear to work for `lightning-tabset` in lwc.  Interestingly aura's tabset has a class attribute, while [lwc tabset does not](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset/specification).  What does that tell us about why the same CSS override solutions do not work for lwc today?

Borrowing from [this solution](https://hellosnl.blogspot.com/2019/07/lwc-override-css-of-standard-lightning-components.html) this seems to work with lwc's tabset.  It admittedly feels very hacky.

```
renderedCallback() {
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerText = `c-vertical .slds-vertical-tabs__nav {
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }`;
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-tabset').appendChild(style);   
}
```

[lwc playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/c51afab4e0c2d4b17c5d8f15d53bce355f310ccd/edit)